# Route page inside a routed page [React]

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem regarding the routing in React.
I have created a Form page. It can be accessed using http://localhost:3000/insert
But I couldn't figure out what URL should I enter if I put `<Form />` in the home.js

In app.js:

```
function App() { 
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>

          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route> 

          <Route exact path="/insert">
            <Form />
          </Route>

        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>  );
}
}
```

In home.js

```
......

 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/insert1">
   <Form />
   </Route>             
 </Switch>

......
```

I have tried http://localhost:3000/insert1 but it won't load.
I only see an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do is

```
<Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}></Route>
```

where 'Contact' is a component